# Designing for Nexus 7 and Nexus 9

Tags: android, android-layout, nexus-7

As per this [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html)

It is said,

> Instead of declaring layouts using the layout-land or layout-port
>   resource folder qualifiers, we strongly recommend switching to the
>   w{N}dp width resource folder qualifier so that content is laid out
>   based on available screen width.

But if I do so for nexus 7 - land, since nexus 7 is `800x1280px` which is `552x960dp` the layout is being picked up from `w600dp` which is a portrait layout.

I have the layout designed for landscape. How should I make it to pick a landscape layout?

Should I place a `w960dp` qualifier? Is that the right way to do?

Comment: Well, does it work as needed if you place it in the w960dp?

Comment: Just ignore it. If what u really need is a landscape use the `land`. Even more, you can combine: `sw600dp-land` (7" land), `sw600dp-port` (7" port), `sw720dp-land` (9" land), `sw720dp-port` (9" port)

Comment: @Budius google itself is strongly recommending to do that, you are suggesting the opposite

Comment: Yes. I am suggesting the opposite. I understand and recognize that some circumstances it would be better to follow the recommendation of using the `width` parameter. But absolutely not is a strong recommendation that should be used all the time. We as developers should know all the resource identifiers and their differences and identify on each case which one is the best to use on the layout we need create. Never follow blindly 1-off recomendation. Because there's no such thing as 1 size fits all.